# Problem passing a variable from one activity to another (Kotlin / Android)

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

This is driving me nuts.
I am taking a number of variables and passing them in a bundle to the same activity. All of the variables are passing through just fine - except for one. It is extremely odd to me because there are 7 other variables that are being assigned and passed in the same manner with no problems.

I know that the variable is being set to the proper value. The problem appears to be either when the variable is being passed or when it is being received. Or something I have no idea about...

As I said, I am bundling the variables and then calling the same activity, which then receives the variables. There is another activity that is used to bring this one up - and the variable passing has the same problem with the exact same variable.

Here is where I bundle the variables

```
            var intentNext= Intent(this@PositionActivityLeft, PositionActivityLeft::class.java)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putBoolean("confirmChoices", confirmChoices)
            bundle.putString("gameType", gameType)
            bundle.putInt("smallBlind", smallBlind)
            bundle.putInt("bigBlind", bigBlind)
            bundle.putInt("buyIn", buyIn)
            bundle.putInt("handsPerHour", handsPerHour)
            bundle.putString("venue", venue)
            bundle.putString("location", location)
            bundle.putString("venueType", venueType)
            bundle.putInt("numSession", numSession)
            bundle.putInt("numSessionHands", numSessionHands)
            bundle.putInt("stackSize", stackSize)
            bundle.putInt("numVillains", numVillainsCount)
            bundle.putString("heroPosition", heroPosition)
            bundle.putString("villain1Position", villain1Position)
            bundle.putString("villain2Position", villain2Position)
            bundle.putString("villain3Position", villain3Position)
            bundle.putString("Villain4Position", villain4Position)
            bundle.putString("villain5Position", villain5Position)
            bundle.putString("villain6Position", villain6Position)
            bundle.putString("villain7Position", villain7Position)
            bundle.putString("villain8Position", villain8Position)
            intentNext.putExtras(bundle)
            startActivity(intentNext)
            overridePendingTransition(0,0)
```

and here is where I read them in:

```
class PositionActivityLeft : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_position_left)

// other variable declarations

        val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
        val confirmChoices = bundle!!.getBoolean("confirmChoices")
        val gameType = bundle.getString("gameType")
        val smallBlind = bundle.getInt("smallBlind")
        val bigBlind = bundle.getInt("bigBlind")
        val buyIn = bundle.getInt("buyIn")
        val handsPerHour = bundle.getInt("handPerHour")
        val venue = bundle.getString("venue")
        val location = bundle.getString("location")
        val venueType = bundle.getString("venueType")
        val numSession = bundle.getInt("numSession")
        val numSessionHands = bundle.getInt("numSessionHands")
        val stackSize = bundle.getInt("stackSize")
        val numVillains = bundle.getInt("numVillains")
        var heroPosition = bundle.getString("heroPosition")
        var villain1Position = bundle.getString("villain1Position","_")
        var villain2Position = bundle.getString("villain2Position","_")
        var villain3Position = bundle.getString("villain3Position","_")
        var villain4Position = bundle.getString("villain4Position","_")
        var villain5Position = bundle.getString("villain5Position","_")
        var villain6Position = bundle.getString("villain6Position","_")
        var villain7Position = bundle.getString("villain7Position","_")
        var villain8Position = bundle.getString("villain8Position","_")
```

for all of the villainPosition variables, I have a default value ("_"). All of the variables pass the intended value of the variable except for villain4Position - it always goes to the default.

I have some code that shows me that the variable is being set properly prior to bundling and sending. It is  the reading that isn't getting through. I have tried changing the variable name, changing the location of the line (moving it up or down) and it's always the same result.

I had originally set up a mutablelistOf for the villainPosition variable which allowed me to do a number of things with much less code, but the 4th variable in the list (index 3) kept having problems. I thought it might have been in how I was iterating things or something, so I went and modified the program to explicitly callout all 8 variables and work with them individually. And the result was exactly the same - the 4th variable is not passing from one activity to another.

Comment: Check `villain4Position` variable for `null` before passing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a typo

The value is stored in the bundle using the key (with an uppercase "V").

```
"Villain4Position"
```

while (with a lowercase "v") is the key used to retrieve the value from the bundle.

```
"villain4Position"
```

To fix this, you should ensure that the bundle key used to retrieve the value matches the one used to put it. Try changing the key used to retrieve the value for

```
"villain4Position" to "Villain4Position"
```